# Database Question (LINQ-to-SQL)

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am currently working on a website where we can track small event for our clients. I am using linq-to-sql and asp.net to build it. So far the site is really small about 10 pages, and only 2 tables, events and clients. I have listed the columns for each table below:

```
Events:
-eventid
-eventname
-datecreated
-details
-datedue
-status
-clientname (this should be clientid)
-sentemail

Clients:
-clientid
-clientname
-clientemail
-clientphone
```

the issue I am having is getting the 2 database tables* to work together. Ideally I would like to have clientname replaced with clientid in the Events table.

I had it set up this way before but ran into an issue when listing out the events:

When I am listing out the events I would like it to show the client name as appose to the clientID. Unfortunately I am pretty new to ASP.net and although I could easily do it in PHP have no idea how to get it to work. Its not a huge deal but I would like to be able to update the client list and events apart from one another.

Sorry If this makes little to no sense, If there is any confusion I will try to word it better.

*correction on my part

Comment: Are the tables stored in separate databases?  I'm confused with the statement "the issue I am having is getting the 2 databases to work together..."  If Events and Clients are two database tables in 1 database the solution is easy.

Comment: Could you add any info on what you've tried exactly and what you've experienced that's different than what you would like to happen?

Comment: are they 2 different databases or 2 different tables in a single database

Comment: sorry just 1 database 2 tables, I don't know whey I stated it that way, must have been late last night ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've got your database normalized, create a Linq2Sql context, and then you can write a query similar to this (to get a list of event names and their client names):

```
var results = from e in dbContext.Events join c in dbContext.Clients on e.clientid equals c.clientid select new { e.eventname, c.clientname };
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I will try this once I finish setting it back to use Ids

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the answer of Andrew Lewis you need to:

1) add the clientid field to the events table

2) run a sql query to fill the clientid field:

```
update events set clientid = (select clientid from client where name = events.clientname)
```

3) remove the clientname field from the events table

Comment: Thank you for the response this should make switching it back much easier